# Replacing values in multiple columns using QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

In QGIS I want to search for a specific case and if this is true then replace the text in multiple columns. Based on [Use updatcursor to replace values in multiple fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115858/use-updatcursor-to-replace-values-in-multiple-fields), [Update multiple fields/columns in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172857/update-multiple-fields-columns-in-qgis) and [Elseif Conditional Statement in QGIS Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39168/elseif-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator)

I have

```
# definition of the function which calculates new values
def upd_value(sfield, svalue, outvalue):
    # criteria
    if search<>svalue:
     outvalue=svalue
     return outvalue

# get the active layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()
prov = layer.dataProvider()

# get the fields
fnm = prov.fieldNameMap() 

# get an iterator for the features
feats = prov.getFeatures()

# calculate new values and update fields with fieldnames
```

I am not sure how to end this. Basically I need the following

```
When
 lower("Given_name")<>lower( "z_Given Names") and 'Surname' is not Null
Then
 "Given_Name" field should be filled with "z_Given_Names"
 "Surname" field should be filled with "z_Surname"
(lots of other fields which I can add in once I know what to do)
 "Status" with 'Updated fields from z table as names not same'


When 
 "Status" = 'V' and "Surname" is Null
Then
 "Given_Name" field should be filled with "z_Given_Names"
 "Surname" field should be filled with  "z_Surname"
 "Status" with 'New'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps use something like the following which focuses on your first `When` statement. Essentially, after you define the fields and expressions for searching and applying values, the script finds all features based on your search expression (e.g. `lower("Given_name")<>lower( "z_Given Names") and 'Surname' is not Null`) and applies the expression for the values for each specified field:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

# Set field names you want to update
field_1 = "Given"
field_2 = "Surname"
idx_1 = layer.fieldNameIndex( field_1 )
idx_2 = layer.fieldNameIndex( field_2 )

# Set expression to find all features which fall into expression
exp = QgsExpression( """ lower("Given_name")<>lower( "z_Given Names") and 'Surname' is not Null """ )
# Select all features which fall into expression
ids = [i.id() for i in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(exp))]
layer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)

# Set expressions to fill in values for selected features
formula_1 = """ "z_Given_Names" """
formula_2 = """ "z_Surname" """
e_1 = QgsExpression(formula_1)
e_2 = QgsExpression(formula_2)

with edit(layer):
    # For each selected feature
    for f in layer.selectedFeatures():
        f[idx_1] = e_1.evaluate(f)
        f[idx_2] = e_2.evaluate(f)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

---

Tested in the Python Console for QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon.

Comment: Hi, I am interested how to do the same in QGIS 3.x?

Comment: @Vitruvius - Hi, you should ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). I am still getting used to the API for QGIS 3 so I'm sure others can help :)