# QGIS find and then replace value in multiple columns

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

This is based on a previous question/answer that I had. [Replacing values in multiple columns using QGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184759/qgis-replace-values-in-multiple-columns)

I need it to update 3 fields now and I get an name 'e' is not defined error. What have I done wrong?

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

# Set field names you want to update
field_1 = "New_Name"
field_2 = "New_File_P"
field_3 = "Process"
idx_1 = layer.fieldNameIndex( field_1 )
idx_2 = layer.fieldNameIndex( field_2 )
idx_3 = layer.fieldNameIndex( field_3 )


# Set expression to find all features which fall into expression
exp = QgsExpression( """ "Existing_F" LIKE '%2015 Aerial Ortho\\_2015\\ECW_Tiles%'  """ )

# Select all features which fall into expression
ids = [i.id() for i in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(exp))]
layer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)

# Set expressions to fill in values for selected features
formula_1 = """ "File_Name" """
formula_2 = """ '\\sipv-gis01\\GIS_Library\\Raster\\Aerial\\2015_25cm\\Images\\ECW' """
formula_3 = """  'y'  """
e_1 = QgsExpression(formula_1)
e_2 = QgsExpression(formula_2)
e_3 = QgsExpression(formula_3)
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

with edit(layer):
    # For each selected feature
    for f in layer.selectedFeatures():
        f[idx_1] = e_1.evaluate(f)
        f[idx_2] = e_2.evaluate(f)
        f[idx_3] = e_3.evaluate(f)

        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Error

```
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

**==== I needed to do this again and here's the QGIS 3x code =====**

```
#search and replace text in all fields of all layers in map

#set text to search for and replace with.
#CAUTION Partial match is allowed
#Based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317855/search-and-replace-text-in-all-fields-in-qgis-3

searchText = "Bougainvilia"
replaceText = "Bougainvillea"

#run on active layer
#layer = iface.activeLayer()

#run on all layers
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
i=1
for layer_id, layer in layers.items():
    print("Layer: %s" % (layer.name()))
    # get data provider
    dpr = layer.dataProvider()
    for field in layer.fields():
        fieldName=field.name()

        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            inText = str(feature[fieldName])
            # get field index
            fieldIndex = layer.fields().indexFromName(fieldName)
            #print ("Checking %s" % (inText))

            if searchText in inText:
                # change inText
                print ("%s . REPLACED: %s in %s with %s in column: %s" % (i, searchText, inText, replaceText, fieldName))
                outText = inText.replace(searchText, replaceText)
                i+=1
                # save changes
                dpr.changeAttributeValues({feature.id(): {fieldIndex: outText}})
print ("Completed")
```

Comment: I don't know python, but what stands 'e' for? don't see any declaration in your code snippet or is it al global variable?

Comment: Is it a typo for the `exp` QgsExpression you declared in line ~20?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part. You shouldn't need that line `e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())`.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph you were correct. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Thanks George but @JochenSchwarze posted an answer which already describes commenting out (or removing) that line so please accept his :)

Comment: @Joseph -I approved this to quick. It appears to work (i.e no errors) but the data fields are not updated. The query works correctly when just run in "select by expression" but not in the code. What else could be wrong?

Comment: @Joseph -can you help with why this isn't working?

Comment: @GeorgeC - Are you running this from the Python Console or from a script? Try adding your last line `layer.updateFeature(f)` directly underneath `f[idx_3] = e_3.evaluate(f)` so there's no extra line between them.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph this didn't work. I am running it from the python console in QGIS.

Comment: @GeorgeC - Are the fields you want to update `String` type?

Comment: Yes, it works fine manually @Joseph

Comment: @GeorgeC - I tested your code on an example shapefile and it works so not exactly sure what's going on. Perhaps if you upload your shapefile to a public server, others could test it and confirm if it's the shapefile that's the problem or not.

Comment: @Joseph -Not sure why it's not working but a test dataset is in the following link. You will need to modify the search to fit with something in this subset of the full dataset. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XGDTNNfbMJZFRJeDlZalF5RVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @GeorgeC - Struggling to find the problem as the code still works and updates the .dbf file. This is after I clear all attributes in the 3 fields you mention in your code and setting the expression to `exp = QgsExpression( """ "File_Type" = 'shp'  """ )`. Don't think I can help much further, sorry -_-

Comment: Updated question to have QGIS 3.x code. Just paste it in to the python editor within QGIS and click on the layer you want to update. Change the search and replace text as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html the member function `QgsExpression.prepare()` is not mandatory but makes the execution faster. I would recommend to comment out the line `e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())` and see what happens.

And as far as I see, an `exp.prepare(...)` is missing directly behind the creation of the expression (i.e. `exp=QgsExpression("""...`) if things run slow, because the expression is evaluated in the next line as an argument to `QgsFeatureRequest(exp)`.

Comment: I approved this to quick. It appears to work (i.e no errors) but the data fields are not updated. The query works correctly when just run in "select by expression" but not in the code. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Hello everyone, does this work with QGIS 3.x and python 3? I failed to repeat this successfully.

Comment: See the updated Q for Python 3x code.